# Show that $E $ is a strictly uniform convex

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis

Let $E$ be a uniformaly convex Banach space such that
$\frac{|x|^2}{2} + \frac{|y|^2}{2} -\left | \frac{x + y}{2} \right |^2 \ge \delta, \quad \forall x,y\in E \, \text{ such that } \, |x|\le M,|y|\le M, |x-y|>\varepsilon.$
Show that $$|tx+(1-t)y|\leq 1-\delta$$
$\forall t\in [\alpha,1-\alpha],\forall \alpha  \in ]0, \frac 12[$ with $|x|\le 1,|y|\le 1, |x-y|>\varepsilon$.
my attempt:
Let $M=1$ we have that $$\frac{|x|^2}{2} + \frac{|y|^2}{2} -\left | \frac{x + y}{2} \right |^2 \ge \delta$$ then $$\left | \frac{x + y}{2} \right |^2 \leq \frac{|x|^2}{2} + \frac{|y|^2}{2} -\delta$$
let $x=2tx$ and $y=2(1-t)y$ we find that $$|tx+(1-t)y|\leq 2t^2|x|^2+2(1-t)^2|y|^2-\delta$$
from  that how  can i reach the right result